# JavaScript Injection On Third-Party Pages

Tags: javascript, subdomain

I've recently stumbled upon a website called [Overlay101](https://www.overlay101.com/) which allows you to create tours for other websites.

I was very interested to see the technique they use to load the third party websites for editing.

When you type the address of the website, it is loaded as a sub domain of the overlay101.com website.

For example, if I type [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) - it is loaded as [`http://stackoverflow.com.www.overlay101.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work`](http://stackoverflow.com.www.overlay101.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

I was wondering how is that subdomain creation achieved and I saw in the source code of the page that JavaScript in injected. I was wondering how was that possible too.

What intrigued me most is that Stackoverflow.com does not allow pages to be loaded within frames - I was wondering how they managed to load up the page so that tour popups could be added.

Comment: I know this is not strictly a programming question - but I've looked everywhere and Stackoverflow is my last place to find answers!

Comment: Notice that you're not logged in on the resulting page, so it's not a frame. I'd guess that it's grabbing and pasting HTML. Also, the subdomain creation is URL-rewriting magic; see Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). (Not present on that page is how to rewrite subdomains but I know one can do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They simply use wildcard DNS entries to make all subdomains work. They then use the `Host` header to get the original domain name and download the HTML code of the site. Since they do this on the server side they do not need any frames etc.